# My page doesn't want to show on the screen, but I can see it clearly in Android Studio preview

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

I made an app project and when I try to click on Profile that leads me to the Profile Settings it does not show anything, but I put a background and some text in the xml file. I see these errors in logcat:

```
E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-0-26097-0](id:65f100000000,api:0,p:-1,c:26097) disconnect: not connected (req=1)
E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
E/ViewRootImpl@f0e9ae3[MainActivity]: Surface is not valid.
```

This is the **xml file**. The ImageView that has final_logo_transparent is an image that I've added as a background and I've used it in other xml files, so it doesn't have to do with that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context=".Profile">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="287dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/final_logo_transparent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="monospace"
        android:paddingHorizontal="80dp"
        android:text="Disconnect"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.98" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profileImage"
        android:layout_width="221dp"
        android:layout_height="202dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="347dp"
        android:src="@drawable/user"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView5"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: please, add some code so we can do something.

Comment: I've added the java file

Comment: your problem is with xml file so please add XML file

Comment: Sorry, now I've added the XML file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you have not **textview2** id anywhere in XML file so, replace it by **textview** in your **Imageview** which contains final_logo_transparent.

**Insted of:**

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
```

**To:**

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
```

Then,

**Replace:**

```
 app:srcCompat="@drawable/final_logo_transparent"
```

**To:**

```
 android:src="@drawable/final_logo_transparent"
```

Try this solution if not work then tell me.

Comment: I still get gray screen as default instead of what I see in the preview

Comment: Now I tried to add a Plain Text and it doesn't show up like it must do. I put the TextColor and TextColorHint to black and I  write something as a hint and it doesn't want to show up

Comment: are you using any api ?

Comment: I think I got the problem. So I named the Java class Profile and Android Studio took it as a library because I saw that Android Studio wanted me to import Profile class